# Woocommerce orders - paying for customers

Tags: woocommerce, orders

I had an issue in Woocommerce that there was no way to make a payment for a customer on the telephone.  Some of our customers are not tech savvy and like to order this way.  I found the below bit of code that removes the login requirement when clicking the 'Customer Payment Page' link to go to the Checkout/Order-pay page, so we can put in payment details for the customer.

Is there any reason this might not be safe?  Of course customer privacy and security is absolutely crucial.

```
function allow_payment_without_login( $allcaps, $caps, $args ) {
    // Check we are looking at the WooCommerce Pay For Order Page
    if ( !isset( $caps[0] ) || $caps[0] != 'pay_for_order' )
        return $allcaps;
    // Check that a Key is provided
    if ( !isset( $_GET['key'] ) )
        return $allcaps;

    // Find the Related Order
    $order = wc_get_order( $args[2] );
    if( !$order )
        return $allcaps; # Invalid Order

    // Get the Order Key from the WooCommerce Order
    $order_key = $order->get_order_key();
    // Get the Order Key from the URL Query String
    $order_key_check = $_GET['key'];

    // Set the Permission to TRUE if the Order Keys Match
    $allcaps['pay_for_order'] = ( $order_key == $order_key_check );

    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'allow_payment_without_login', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Enable guest checkout so they don't need to log in.

Comment: These are telephone customers who want to order on the phone. We usually encourage people to order online, but some are elderly and dont want to use computers.

Comment: Also we have guest checkout enabled but when a customer receives a link to pay they still need to login.